# Where are the Flash temp/cache files in safari 9? They move every version

Tags: safari, macos, adobe-flash

Safari 9.0.2 under yosemite and el capitan: looking for where the cached flash video files are stored. It seems they change location every time there is an OS or Safari update. And are they accessible via Web Inspector when I have the page loaded/video running?

Answer (score 1):

In the past it used to be possible to find cached Flash video files and retain them.

However that doesn't seem possible in recent versions. There are a few "Cache" folders created if you install Flash Player (or use the one bundled with Google Chrome), but when a Flash video is actually playing the data appears to be written temporarily to a location similar to `/private/var/folders/t5/zp1103fj4h924mvzysl1m9wh0000gn/T/FlashTmp.T6ja08` but it doesn't stick around long.